# Are there any Gedit plugins for Rails

Tags: gedit, plugins, rails

I have watched some video tutorials for rails and spotted gedit as very good editor for ruby on rails development.

I installed gmate and some plugins for programming (autocomplete and intelligent text completion) but I still cannot achieve what this guy has on video at 5.18 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g3SuV-A9bak

When he types def index, it automatically adds code for whole method stub.

Does anyone knows which plugin is this?

If you know any other plugins that can provide more comfortable rails programming, they are welcome.

Comment: mmmh i don't know about gedit but sublime text 2 is good for ruby/rails

Comment: I have just installed it, it is cool but still does not support this "snippeting". thanks

Answer (score 0):

Select Code Snippets in Plugin. Simple.[image: Aptana code completion] I just wrote def and immediate tab. def(tab) and it gave me options.

Comment: You can use Aptana, Since I too do use it. Everything most often comes preconfigured in Aptana. Just you need to have RVM RoR installed, than install JAva and APatana, Simple . Only issue is that Aptana is slow in Windows,but ok with Ubuntu because of JAva. but Gedit is pretty fast IDE and best. And I heard that Gedit 3 got issue with Gmate. May be new version of that is coming up. So till than you cant try this solution. And if possible Aptana if you want to try

Comment: @SonOfOmer  Sure, And in Gedit as you require you have to got for View>Highlight Mode> Scripting and select RubyonRails to get that working in your gedit, if you wanted to test it worked

Comment: I have just installed Aptana 3 on Ubuntu, and it is missing the feature that I have described in question, while in the same time Aptana 3 on windows has it.

Comment: @SonOfOmer. Aptana got all those fully needed plugin for any Web development required. I have to just def and tab immediate. Try it

Comment: I am just trying it on ubuntu. I type for example def index and then enter, it does nothing, just go to the next line. But the same Aptana on windows, it the same scenario generate code 'end' for def index. Thanks

Comment: In windows there is no need to press tab, after I write name of the function and press enter it generates the end. Can I have it on ubuntu? Thanks

Comment: @SonOfOmer In aptana, you just need to type def(tab) that is all. As I posted on image, I just typed Def and tabbed it.

Comment: Not in aptana for Windows, in windows there is no need to press tab, after I write name of the function and press enter it generates the "end".